# Angular 2 - Event after innerHtml has been rendered

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a div element where the innerHtml is bound to a string(html) property.

```
<div  [effectDirectiveTrigger]="mainContent != null"   
      [innerHtml]="mainContent"></div>
```

I am trying to build a directive that "fire some effects" after the div with its innerHtml is completely rendered. Therefor i have a trigger-property.

```
@Input('effectDirectiveTrigger')
trigger:boolean = false;

ngOnChanges(){
    console.log('ngOnChanges');
    if (this.trigger){
        // fire some effects
        // seems to happen before the innerHtml has been rendered
    }
}
```

My problem is that even if the property has been triggered, the innerHtml is not yet written. Angular seems to need some time for that. It only works if it set an ungly timeout to allow angular to catch up.

Is there an event i could bind to? Or do you have any other/better idea to achieve what i am trying to do? Could jQuery help?

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` is updated every time `mainContent` is updated and the following change detection cycle has happened. There is no event. You can emit an event yourself after `mainContent` was updated. If you invoke change detection yourself with `cdRef.detectChanges()` then you now it's rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html
`ngAfterViewInit` should work.

Comment: Already tried `ngAfterViewInit`. It happens way to early and even before the last `ngOnChanges` -  **mainContent** is loaded **asynchronously**.

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit` is a _component-only hook_ That may be the reason why it does not help in my case.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a plunker or so?